# jQuery hover with fadeIn lose focus when mouse is moved quickly

Tags: jquery, performance, hover

For example I have 4 images that change when using jQuery `.hover` combined with `fadeIn`, which work  fine, but if you move the mouse quickly over the images things get wierd, hover fails and the function generally degrades into a mess.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BD5EZ/ moving the mouse quickly over images and they get all messed up.

How can I improve this so that the images which do not have a hover effect actually go back to their original state, and that the generally snappiness of the effect is fast?

```
      var sourceIn = function () {
         var $this = $(this);
         var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
         $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
         $this.fadeOut(function () {
             $this.attr('src', newSource).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
         });
      }
      $(function () {
         $('img.toggle').hover(sourceIn);
      });
```

I have also tried to use `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` (on a seperate function) but the effect is generally the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd approach the probelm a little differently.

first up I would change your markup to have two images per `</li>`:

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img class="toggle" src="http://i.imgur.com/sQ3ANRNb.jpg">
            <img class="toggle" src="http://i.imgur.com/H9cvzaOb.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="toggle" src="http://i.imgur.com/sQ3ANRNb.jpg">
            <img class="toggle" src="http://i.imgur.com/H9cvzaOb.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="toggle" src="http://i.imgur.com/sQ3ANRNb.jpg">
            <img class="toggle" src="http://i.imgur.com/H9cvzaOb.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would then add some CSS to style the images such that the second image is displayed behind the first.

```
#slider ul li {
    position: relative;
}
#slider ul li img:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Finally I would use the following updated JQuery that just changes the opacity when you over on the "top" image:

```
$('#slider ul li img:first-child').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 1000);
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 1000);

});
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/BD5EZ/2/**

Obviously if you want to speed up the transition it is just a case of changing the `1000`'s to a smaller figure!

---

## EDIT

Even easier JQuery, I forgot about the [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) function!

```
$('#slider ul li img:first-child').hover(function () {
    $(this).fadeToggle();
});
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/BD5EZ/4/**

Comment: Thanks, this is what I had originally and I have gone back to it, CSS just makes for an easier DOM load and transition.

Answer (score 1):

i would store the original src attr in variable and the code will look like this

```
$(function () {
  var srced;
  $('img.toggle').hover(function(){
         srced = $(this).attr('src');  
         $(this).attr('style','opacity:0');
         $(this).addClass('hovered').animate({'opacity':'1'},500).attr('src',$(this).data('alt-src'));
       }, function(){     
         $(this).attr('style','opacity:0');
         $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500).attr('src',srced).removeClass('hovered');
       });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BD5EZ/6/)